# Can we use classes as header

Tags: c++

I was reading c++ primer book. But in an example of class, it was using the class as header.

```
#include<iostream>
#include"sales_item.h" //here, it uses class as header
int main()
{
Sales_item total;
if(std::cin>>total) {
sales_item trans;
while(std::cin>>trans) {
.....
```

So please tell me how to use it, so that I can compile it in CodeBlocks IDE.

Comment: How is `sales_item.h` a class?

Comment: `sales_item.h` is a file, just like any other file.

Comment: @K-ballo sorry, it is not a class, it is a header, but later in the program objects are made on that header file.

Comment: sales_item.h probably defines a class which is used in other files.

Comment: @chris please check the program code now.

Comment: I Apologize for my mistakes, I have just started learning c++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example there is used a header as header.:) That is the class definition is placed in separate header `sales_item.h` that is included in a module where the class definition is used. The class itself is named as `Sales_item`.

Comment: @user3319978 What procedure are you speaking about?

Comment: How to define class inside a header.

Comment: @user3319978, Without having read the book, I can only be 99.9% sure the book goes into great detail on that.

Comment: BTW, what are the advantages and disadvantages of defining class inside a header file?

Comment: @user3319978 The main advantage that you need not to retype the class definition if you are going to use it in several modules. it is enough to include the header that contains the definition in each module.

Answer (score 0):

it is called separate compilation. C++ supports separate compilation, where pieces of the program can be compiled independently through the two stage approach of compilation and then linking, so changes to one class would not necessarily require the re-compilation of the other classes

Comment: No, header files are not an example of separate compilation. Separate compilation is when you have two .cpp files.